# ExceptionInInitializerError - static final variables

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

The following code sometimes produces `ExceptionInInitializerError`.
Apparently the static variable `res` is `null` although it is used after it should have been initialized.
What could be the reason?

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private static final Resources res = App.getAppContext().getResources();
    public static final String foo = res.getString(R.string.foo); //NullPointer here
}

public class App extends Application {
    private static Context context;
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }   
    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not save values of resources in `static` fields in the first place. Those values need to change based upon configuration changes. In your case, when the user chooses a new locale, you will need the proper translation for `R.string.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access resources before app initialize. `static` fields are generated in `.dex` file with static definition, mean they should be static like `"foo"`. But you can not use resources in static initialization with app resources.

Change your activity class by this.

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private static Resources res;
    public static String foo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@android.support.annotation.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        res = App.getAppContext().getResources();
        foo = res.getString(R.string.foo);
    }
}
```

By the way why you need to create Resources object when you have directly access to `getString` method in `Activity` class

You can just do this.

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    public static String foo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@android.support.annotation.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        foo = getString(R.string.foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Declare variables then after get a value in onCreate(), you missed onCreate() method.

```
 public class GameActivity extends Activity {
        Context context;
 private static Resources res;
    public static String foo;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_address);
            context = this;
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            res = App.getAppContext().getResources();
            foo = res.getString(R.string.foo); //NullPointer here
        }

        public class App extends Application {
            private static Context context;

            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
                context = getApplicationContext();
            }

            public static Context getAppContext() {
                return context;
            }
        }
    }
```

Directly you can get a lause of string from `string.xml` file like this

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;
    public String foo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_address);
        context = this;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        foo = getString(R.string.foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `res = App.getAppContext().getResources()` just call `res = getApplicationContext().getResources()`.